# Como hacer que my switch muestre la estacion del año y no que simplemente no muestra nada al poner el mes?

Tags: c#, xaml

Tengo este codigo que usa switch para visualizar las estaciones basado en la respuesta del mes, esta hecho  C# y XAML, pero no funciona. Soy nuevo en este mundo. He probado hacerlo con otros funciones como usando TryParse o Parse, pero igual no funciona, simplemente no hace nada. Alguna idea,por favor? Gracias

Codigo en lenguage C#

```
            string month2;
            
            switch (month2)
            {
                case "January":
                case "February":
                case "December":

                  question2.Text = "Winter";
                    break;
                case "March":
                case "April":
                case "May":
                    question2.Text = "Spring";
                    break;

                case "June":
                case "July":
                case "August":
                    question2.Text = "Summer";
                    break;
                case "September":
                case "October":
                case "November":
                    question2.Text = "Fall";
                    break;

                    question2.Text = "Category is " + month2;
            }
```

Este es la parte del codigo en lenguaje XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Fortune_Teller.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Text="Welcome Fortune Teller!" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
        </Frame>
        <Label FontSize="16" Padding="30,24,30,0">            
            
        <Label Text="Enter your Month birth, please" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Blue" FontSize="36"/>

        <Entry x:Name="month"  Placeholder="Enter text" />

        <Button Text="Click here for answer!"
                   
                Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                 Margin="5"              
                 HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                FontSize="Large"
                TextColor="Blue"/>
        
        <Label x:Name="question2"
               Text="Answer" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Blue" FontSize="36"/>

    </StackLayout>
   
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Ese codigo, no hace absolutamente nada.. si definis una variable para el string, y no le das valor, no tiene valor.. vos que esperabas? obtener el mes ingresado por el usuario?

Comment: Hola. En que momento haces el mapeo de la variable `month` en xaml a la variable `month2` en C#?

Comment: Hola,Alfabravo,he hecho el mapeo de la variable month en xaml a la variable month2 en C# y el resultado es igual. Gracias

Comment: He hecho esto tambien y nada, no funciona. Gracias                                                       int optionPicked =0 ;

            string month = "";
                     
            if (month == "December" || month == "January" || month == "February") optionPicked = 1;
            ....................................
                case 1:
                    question2.Text = ($" You are a Winter person");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    question2.Text = ($" You are a spring person");
                    ........................

Answer (score 0):

```
question2.Text = "Category is " + month2;
```

Está escrito dentro del ámbito ( las llaves `{ }` ) del *`switch`* , pero no pertenece a ningún *`case`*, ni tampoco es un codigo *`default`* ( default : para cuando no se ajusta a ningun case descrito en el *`switch`* ), dentro del *`switch`*.

saca esta linea `question2.Text = "Category is " + month2;`

y colócala despues de la segunda, la última llave del *`switch`* ..

```
   string month2 = "";
            
            switch (month2)
            {
                case "January":
                case "February":
                case "December":

                  question2.Text = "Winter";
                    break;
                case "March":
                case "April":
                case "May":
                    question2.Text = "Spring";
                    break;

                case "June":
                case "July":
                case "August":
                    question2.Text = "Summer";
                    break;
                case "September":
                case "October":
                case "November":
                    question2.Text = "Fall";
                    break;

            }

        question2.Text = "Category is " + month2;
```

Ten en cuenta también que ..

La variable *`string month2`*, tal como has compartido el código, está sin inicializar. Declárala, inicialízala.

Usar variables sin inicializar, pueden generar errores. Si no es que estás teniendo en cuenta, que hasta que las inicialices pueden contener valor **NULL**, y lo usas así por algo muy concreto, específicamente, teniendo en cuenta lo que conlleva.

Además de que no se les puede asignar el valor **NULL** a todos los tipos de variables, por lo que en cuanto hagas cualquier otra cosa de esta manera con una variable -de estas- luego de haberla declarado, va a fallar.

***Inicializar las variables al declararlas, antes de usarlas está comprendido dentro lo descrito como de buenas prácticas de programación.***

```
month2 = "";
```

Aunque, fijate que ..

Está en el ámbito del método del *`switch`*, tú sabrás como manejas lo siguiente :

En el código XAML que has compartido, no veo donde o como, introduces el dato del mes, en *`month2`* en tiempo y forma, antes del *`switch`*.

Así que, sino la declaras, y no introduces el dato antes de que llegue al *`switch`*, *`month2`* llega a la instrucción *`switch`* con valor **`NULL`** al ejecutar, y no procesará para nada el dato de un mes : fallará, de hecho.

Debes asignar a *`month2`*, le valor, la cadena del dato, antes de procesar *`month2`* en el *`switch`*, con un evento, o de algún otro modo.